# How to determine which encoding to use, when reading from a serial port

Tags: c#, encoding, serial-port

I am new to c# and I try to read the serial port, but it results in some strange characters. I do not know what encoding shall I use.

I tried to use `GetEncoding("utf-8")` which results in some strange characters and using  `BitConverter.ToString` I can see the hex output.

Can some one point me out in the right direction, where I am doing the mistake?

Using `GetEncoding("utf-8")`

```
private void port_DataRecieved(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort port = (SerialPort)sender;
    byte[] data = new byte[port.BytesToRead];
    port.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    TextBox.Text += "'Rx:'"+Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(data)+"\n";
}
```

Output is as follows:

[image: ![Output when using utf-6 encoding]

Using `BitConverter.ToString`

```
private void port_DataRecieved(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort port = (SerialPort)sender;
    int bytes = port.BytesToRead;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
    port.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
    if (BitConverter.ToString(buffer).Replace("-", " ").Length > 1)
    { 
        TextBox.Text += "'Rx:'"+BitConverter.ToString(buffer).Replace("-", " ")+"'\n";
    }
}
```

Output is as follows:

[image: Output when using Bytes string]

Comment: The encoding depends entirely upon the device that has been plugged in. Consulting with the documentation of that device should lead you to an answer. The data might not even be text.

Comment: Do not use encoding when you have binary data.  Only encode the binary data to text on fields that are really text.